# Joint pdf of $f(x,y)=e^{-(x+y)}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I am asked to find the joint pdf of $\ f(x,y)=e^{-(x+y)} $
where $x,y$ are between $0$ and $\infty$ or $0$ otherwise.

I can see its an exponential distribution, which means its continuous so I started a double integral like this:

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}e^{-y} dy dx$

I tried substituting in $u=e^{-x}$ and $du= -e^{-x} $

$v=e^{-y}$ and $\int v= \int   e^{-y}dy=-e^{-y} $

My result after substituting y for 0 and $\infty$ is $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}-e^{-x}dx$ = $-e^{-x}-e^{-x}$ and with limits applied I get $2$. 
I can see that the answer should be EXP(1) since the exponential pdf is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x} $ so for my example $\ e^{-(x+y)} $ it must be $1$. (EXP(1) is the answer in the back of the text book for the marginal pdfs).
Am I on the right track with my integration please or am I doing all of this wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It looks as though you're trying to do integration by parts. As far as I'm aware, you wouldn't use that for a multivariable integral (unless the integrand with respect to one variable required it). Instead, pick a variable to integrate first, say, $y$. Then integrate $e^{-y} dy$, treating $e^{-x}$ as constant. You should find that the whole thing evaluates to $1$. Beyond that, are you sure that's the question? You write "find the joint pdf", but the equation you give *is* the joint pdf.

Comment: Also, note that the integral you write, $\int e^{-x} - e^{-x} dx$, is equal to $0$ (or, not skipping any steps, $\int 0 dx$) regardless of the limits of integration.

Comment: Sorry, I worded that poorly. The question stated "A joint pdf is given by f(x,y)$\ f(x,y)=e^{-(x+y)}$. Find the marginal pdf's and find the joint CDF, F(x,y)." The book had a similar example which I was trying to follow (and failing miserably). The answer to the marginal pdf question is Exp(1) for both x and y.

Comment: I'm just noticing this last part: Are you saying the answer (as in the book's answer?) for either one of the marginal pdfs is the number $e = 2.718 \ldots$?

Comment: Yes, the text book's answer to the problem was simply "Exp(1) for both". That's their answer to the marginal pdf question. I really wish they had some examples or working.

Comment: Well, a marginal pdf is a function; $e$ is a constant. In general, the only constant pdfs one sees are for uniform distributions. So that's kind of strange... Otherwise, how did you make out with the cdf?

Comment: @dmk The books implies the exp(1) distribution, that is the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda=1$. It does not mean the constant $e^1$. To Helena: What do you mean in the question when you say "Find the joint pdf?" It is given. Do you mean find the marginal pdf??

Comment: @Stefanos: I'd never seen that shorthand before, oddly enough, but I probably should have inferred it :). As for Helena's question, she clarified it in the comments; see my answer below.

Comment: @dmk Ok, thanks for the clarification, I will answer it although you have already noted a correct hint.

Answer (score 1):

Try the fact that $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{(-x-y)}dxdy=\int_0^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-y} e^{u}(du)\right)dy=\int_0^\infty e^{-y}dy=1$$

here letting $u=-x-y$ and $du=-dx$ (why?). But I am not sure if this is what you need to find for your problem in general, as prior commenters have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

For the marginal pdfs, note that you split up $e^{-(x+y)}$ into the product of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$. Or rather, note that it was *possible* to do this. That says something about whether or not the two variables are independent. What does it say? What then can we say about the marginal pdfs?

As for the joint cdf, I think there's some sort of, uh, formula the books generally give us, but I'm no good at remembering formulas. What if, instead of integrating

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-x} e^{-y} \, dy \, dx$$

you integrated

$$\int_0^a \int_0^b e^{-x} e^{-y} \, dy \, dx$$

? That would get you $F(a, b)$. Let me know if you have any questions.